# How to set action bar menu items formatting using style.xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I am totally new to android.

I made my own action bar with the code below :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings123"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I want to change the properties (like color, background) of item(s) under menu list(Currently having only single item 'Settings')

Here what I did in my style.xml for it :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/menuIconFormatting</item>

         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    </style>
    <style name="menuIconFormatting" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBarHave you tried adding the property android:actionBarStyle? Put this inside of your AppTheme

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyAwesomeActionBarStyle</item>
```

Now style it however you want

```
<style name="MyAwesomeActionBarStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:background">SOME_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">SOME_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
```

I hope this sets you on the right track :)